# escape angular brackets in jQuery.parseXML()

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am getting a text response from a server which looks like `<label>&lt;sometext&gt;my Label&lt;/sometext&gt;</label>` . The problem is when I do a `jQuery.parseXML()` to create an xml document out of this response. It ends up creating `<label><sometext>my Label</sometext></label>`. How can I escape these angular brackets while parsing the xml?

Comment: What exactly do you want the output to be?

Comment: @BenElliott it's said in the question

Comment: @smarber Can you express it as a string? Did you want the output to be a single `label` node with content `&lt;sometext&gt;my Label&lt;/sometext&gt;` or did you want the tree `label` > `sometext` > `"my Label"`?

Comment: @BenElliott yes, absolutely!

Comment: @newbie which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&lt;` and `&gt;` are HTML entities that allow you to print the less-than (`<`) and greater-than (`>`) characters in an XML/HTML-like document without them being parsed as tags.

There are two ways to interpret your question and I'm not sure which you mean, so I'll try to solve both:

1. **You want JQuery to "ignore" the already-escaped characters** - this means JQuery should parse your string as a `label` node with text content `"<sometext>my Label</sometext>"` (remember that `&lt;` will display as `<` in the parsed HTML), i.e.

   ```
   label
       |--- "<sometext>my Label</sometext>"
   ```

This is almost certainly what JQuery is already doing. It's hard to see it, as the characters will print the same, but you can verify it by trying the following:

```
var result = $.parseXML("<label>&lt;sometext&gt;myLabel&lt;/sometext&gt;</label>");
console.log(result);
console.log(result.children[0].textContent);
```

The third line wil print `"<sometext>myLabel</sometext>"`, i.e. this string is the text content of your `label` tags and not another node itself (if it was, it would show up in `result.children[0].children[0]` instead).

2. **You want JQuery to treat the escaped characters as tag markers** - the other option is that you *do* want JQuery to consider `sometext` as another XML node, giving:

   ```
   label
       |---sometext
            |---"my Label"
   ```

This one would be best solved by having your server send the unescaped characters in the string payload. But alternatively you can replace the characters in the string like so:

```
var string = "<label>&lt;sometext&gt;myLabel&lt;/sometext&gt</label>"
.replace(/&[l|g]t;/g, function(c) {
  if (c === "&lt;") {
    return "<";
  } else {
    return ">";
  }
});

var result = $.parseXML(string);
console.log(result);
console.log(result.children[0]);
console.log(result.children[0].children[0].textContent);
```

The final line prints `my Label`, showing that `sometext` was indeed parsed as a parent node.

**Edit: just thought of a third interpretation**

3. **You want to be able to display the escaped characters literally, i.e. as `&lt;` rather than `<`** - This would give the following tree:

   ```
   label
       |--- "&lt;sometext&gt;my Label&lt;/sometext&gt;"
   ```

To achieve this you can again use a function to replace the characters:

```
var string = "<label>&lt;sometext&gt;myLabel&lt;/sometext&gt;</label>".replace(/&[l|g]t;/g, function(c) {
  if (c === "&lt;") {
    return "&amp;lt;";
  } else {
    return "&amp;gt;";
  }
});

result = $.parseXML(string);
```

Here we escape the ampersand `&` so that the entity is not recognised as a whole.